# Create 2 objects for each element of a Java stream

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, collectors

Is there a way to create 2 different objects for each element of a stream and collect them all at last?

For example,
if I have a `List<String> stringList` and have a class `GoddClass` with a default and a `customConstructor`, I want to create 2 objects in one stream and collect at last

```
stringList
  .stream()
  .map(GoddClass::new) 
  .addAnothrObject(GoddClass::customConstructor) // Not a valid line, Just to depict what is needed
  .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

One stream might not be the right solution to achieve what I'm trying. But the question is out for experts.

Comment: Take a look at `flatMap`

Comment: @AniketSahrawat Can you elaborate?  I've used `flatMap()`, when I had a steam mapping resulting another stream, or similar cases, but how do you fit `flatMap` in this scenario

Comment: Create a method that returns a `List<GoddClass>` with both those objects accepting a string as input and use `flatMap` to call it like `...stream().flatMap(str -> method(str).stream()).collect....`

Answer (score 6):

`.flatMap` with `Stream.of` is most suitable in this case.

```
stringList
 .stream().flatMap(str -> Stream.of(new GoddClass(), new GoddClass(str))
 .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: when you use above you get.`Cannot infer type argument(s) for <R> flatMap(Function<? super T,? extends Stream<? extends R>>)`

Comment: @ThrowableException Could you provide a minimal, reproducible example?